# How to call custom made function using via parameter in laravel notification?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-notification

devs,I am using laravel 8 I create a notification inside that I made my own funciton toTwilio mention below code.

Problem: how can I call that function. I include in return parameter of via() function
but it shows me "driver [twilio] not supported.". I do not register anything
anywhere. and I tried to change the name of function still showing error
"driver[<fun_name>] not supported.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class DepartmentNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['toTwilio'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    public function toTwilio($notifiable)
    {
        echo "twilio hit";
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the official documentation about custom notification channels here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#custom-channels.

First of all You should create a `TwilioChannel` class to call `toTwilio` method:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Channels;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class TwiolioChannel
{
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $message = $notification->toTwilio($notifiable);

        // Send notification to the $notifiable instance...
    }
}
```

After creating Channel class change notification `via` method  like this:

```php
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [TwilioChannel::class];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find more details on here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#sending-notifications.

But basically, you could send notifications in following two ways:

**1) Using `notifiable` trait**

```
use Notifiable;

$user->notify(new DepartmentNotification());
```

**2) Using Notification Facade**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

Notification::send($users, new DepartmentNotification());
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to queue the notifications. This means you might have to run, `php artisan queue:work` as well.

Comment: I did the same . the problem is that  toTwilio function is not calling and throws the error.